# angular 8 function params is undefined on subscribe

Tags: javascript, rxjs, angular8

i have 2 functions, inside i do http call and subscribe to that.
in the update function inside the subscribe the outer function param is available to me but in the deleteDeviceGroup function the groupId param is undefined inside the subscribe.
why there is difference between them?

```
update(id, device: Partial<IDevice>) {
    this.devicesDataService.updateDevice(id, device).subscribe(res => {
      debugger;
      if (res['status'] && res['status'] === 204) {
        this.devicesStore.update(id, device);
      }
    });
  }
 deleteDeviceGroup(groupId: string) {
    this.deviceGroupDataService.deleteGroup(groupId).subscribe(deleted => {
      // TODO: remove entity from store
    });
  }


@Component({
  selector: 'marketplace-device-groups',
  templateUrl: './device-groups.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./device-groups.component.scss']
})
export class DeviceGroupsComponent extends DeviceGroupsBaseComponent
  implements OnInit {
  constructor(public deviceGroupService: DeviceGroupService) {
    super(deviceGroupService);
  }
  deleteGroup(group): void {
    const groupId = group.id;
    this.deviceGroupService.deleteDeviceGroup(groupId);
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    super.ngOnInit();
  }
}

export class DeviceGroupCardComponent implements OnInit {
  isDropdownOpen: Boolean = false;
  @Input() deviceGroup: IDeviceGroup;
  @Output() deleteGroup: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() {}
  toggleDropdown() {
    if (this.isDropdownOpen) {
      this.isDropdownOpen = false;
    } else {
      this.isDropdownOpen = true;
    }
  }
  deleteGroupClick() {
    this.isDropdownOpen = false;
    console.log(this.deviceGroup);

    this.deleteGroup.emit(this.deviceGroup);
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}

<div class="dropdown-menu" id="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a
            routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
            (click)="deleteGroupClick()"
            class="dropdown-item"
          >
            Delete Group
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the `id` parameter belongs to the `update` function scope. It's not meant to be available elsewhere, it's actually inteded. Subscribe handles just a callback, hence it inherits from the outer scope the variables visibility. In your case, the first subscribe inherits `id` and `device`, while `deleteGroup`'s subscribe inherits `groupId`, hence `id` does **not** belong to `deleteDeviceGroup` in any way, unless there is a global `id` somewhere else.

Comment: sorry i not  explained correctly , what i mean is in the deleteDeviceGroup subscribe the groupId is not available. i edited the question

Comment: Are you **100% sure** that upon the `deleteDeviceGroup` call `groupId` was defined first?

Comment: Did you check what's the value of groupId in the params when the function is called?

Comment: yes 100% it was defined. i also get success on the response i just need the groupId in the subscribe to delete from the store.  i can put the id on the this of the service but i want to understand why it is not available to me as in the update method

Comment: The only feasible case I can think of is that `groupId` is somewhere referenced and deleted **before** the subscribe callback is invoked, which sounds weird and shouldn't happen at all. May you please share the relevant part that invokes the `deleteDeviceGroup` method?

Comment: i have edited and put the code. i have the view that i click on deleteGroupClick() and it emits the value in the deleteGroupClick function to the DeviceGroupsComponent  and calls the service

Comment: Could you share code from *device-groups.component.html*

Comment: <div class="columns is-multiline">
  <div class="column is-4" *ngFor="let device of ($deviceGroups | async)">
    <marketplace-device-group-card
      [deviceGroup]="device" (deleteGroup)="deleteGroup($event)"
    ></marketplace-device-group-card>
  </div>
</div>

Comment: solved this. when i replace the debugger with console.log(groupId) it works . but with the debugger its undefined... very weird